# How to create a map (UIImage) with buttons on it that animate?

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimage, uibutton

i have a map (just an image) and i want that a user can click on some places on the map.  I think i can do that with adding buttons as subviews. But i also want to animate them.  So for example  want to have a ring form around the link position. And this ring should animate like pulsing or so. How can i do that the best way?

greets Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why nobody has tried to answer this but it's not too difficult.

First, create a `UIImageView` and configure it to animate your desired effect. The UIImageView documentation is very clear on what to do. Something like:

```
NSArray *imageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame1.png],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame2.png],
                       ...,nil];

UIImageView *animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
animatedImageView.animatedImages = imageArray;
animatedImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubView:animatedImageView];
[animatedImageView startAnimating];
```

You then have to add the code to respond to touch events on the imageView.

Alternatively, you can create a UIButton subclass that displayed an animated UIImageView per above and then use the standard `addTarget:action` to respond to user actions.